# Coil winding direction in a shaded-pole motor (4-pole)

Tags: electromagnetism, winding, ac-motor

I have rewound a shaded-pole motor (4-pole).

It's wound around the stator in a clockwise motion and around each coil in a counter clockwise motion.

Is the winding being incorrect the reason why the motor does not rotate?

Comment: Perhaps some pictures of your work would help

Answer (score 0):

A picture would help, but the 4 poles need to alternate in polarity to get motion.  You don't need to rewind, just swap the connections on two of the coils.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how you have carried out the winding.

This diagram clearly shows how it's to be done.

[image]

*Image credit: [Electrical4U](https://www.electrical4u.net/induction-motor/shaded-pole-induction-motor-working-advantages-power-rating/#google_vignette)*